# prove that $(n^2)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^{n+1}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

(1) How can we prove that $(kn)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^k$, where $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$

(2) How can we prove that $(n^2)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^{n+1}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

(3) How can we prove that $(k!)!$ is divisible by $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$, where $k\in \mathbb{N}$

$\bf{My\; Try}::(1) $ We know that product of $n$ consecutive integer is divisible by $n!$

So Here  $1.2.3.4........................................n$ is divisible by $n!$

Similarly $(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdot(n+3)...........(2n)$ is divisible by $n!$

Similarly $(2n+1)\cdot (2n+2)\cdot ..............(3n)$ is divisible by $n!$

Similarly $(3n+1)\cdot(3n+2)......................(4n)$ is divisible by $n!$

.............................................................

.............................................................

Similarly $\{(k-1)n+1\}\cdot \{(k-1)n+2\}\cdot..................\{(k-1)n+n\}$ is divisible by $n!$

So we can say that $(kn)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^k$

Now I did not understand how can i  solve $(II)$ one and $(III)$ one

Help Required

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{(n^2)!}{n!^{n+1}}$$
is the number of paritions of an $n^2$ element set into $n$ (indistinguishable) sets of size $n$ each.

$(3)$ is just a special case of $(1)$ with $k\leftarrow (k-1)!$ and $n\leftarrow k$.

Answer (score 3):

(3) is a direct consequence of (1), as (after a change of name to avoid confusion) $(h!)! = (h(h-1)!)!$ so applying (1) with $n=h$ and $k=(h-1)!$, you get that $(h(h-1)!)!$ is divisible by $(h!)^{(h-1)!}$.

For (2), you have actually that

$$(k+1)n! \mid (kn+1)⋅(kn+2)⋅\dots·((k+1)n)$$

is divisible by $(k+1)n!$, in fact, if you take out the last term, you get

$$(n-1)! \mid (kn+1)⋅(kn+2)⋅\dots·((k+1)n-1)$$

just because it's the product of $(n-1)$ consecutive integers. Then you multiply by $(k+1)n$ both sides, obtaining that

$$(n-1)!·(k+1)n \mid (kn+1)⋅(kn+2)⋅\dots·((k+1)n-1)·(k+1)n$$

So $n^2!$ can be expressed as a product of

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}kn+i = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}P_k
$$

And each $P_k$ is divisible by $(k+1)n!$ so the entire product is divisible by

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)n! = n!^{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** Consider the multinomial coefficient
$$kn \choose n, n,\dots,n$$
that is an integer.

**Hint 2:** Follow the @Hagen von Eitzen's method!

**Hint 3:** Consider the multinomial coefficient
$$k! \choose k,k,\dots,k$$

Answer (score 1):

3 is simple,

plug n = k, m = (k - 1)! into $(mn)!$  is divisible by $(n!)^m$

Going to submit answer to two shortly.

**Edit**

I am trying to use a proof by induction for 2.

The 0th case (1) is simple $(1^2)! = 1$ and $(1!)^{1+1} = 1$ obviously  $1 | 1$ so that case works.

All that needs to be done is to prove that $(n^2)! | (n!)^{n+1} \rightarrow ((n+1)^2)! | ((n+1)!)^{n+2}$